# In core php i am try to send mail but mail() function not working?

Tags: php

I am try to send an email but on localhost mail function not working?

```
$subject = "Test mail"; 
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message."; 
$from = "123@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from; 
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers); 
echo "Mail has been Sent.";
```

Comment: What OS, What webserver?

Comment: Try to check whether you have an MTA configured, e.g. Postfix.

Comment: If only `mail()` would return `false` on error...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mail server for that.

If you are running windows: http://www.hmailserver.com/

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` is doing its part to get a mail on the way. But it can only do so much ... If there's no local MTA installed, it'll fail. Also: Check the return value of `mail()`.